# JQuery li color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to change the color of li on click via this code:

```
$(function(){
        $("li").click(function (){
                $(this).css("color","green")
        });

... more code
```

but none of the li elements will work. The li elements are dynamically generated in the more code section.

Comment: Do you receive an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you deal with dynamically generated content you need to attach the event handler to an element on the page like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function (){
                $(this).css("color","green")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Click() do not work with dynamic html, use on() method, bind click on parent with click on li element

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#parentID").on('click','li',function (){
                $(this).css("color","green")
        });
```

where parentID will be the ID of the parent for all dynamically generated content